# Connected components of a topological space and Zorn's lemma

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I have just come across the idea of a connected component of a topological space. And firstly I would just like some clarity on the definition, as it seemed a little vague. Here is what I understand the precise definition to be:

> Given a topological space $X$ then $A \subset X$ is a connected component of $X$ iff $A$ is connected in its subspace topology.

Hopefully this definition is correct. My main question is that can one conclude that $X$ is the disjoint union of maximal connected components (ordered by inclusion) iff Zorn's lemma is assumed? I.e to get that maximal connected components exists, do we need Zorn's lemma?

Answer (score 3):

"$A$ is a component" implies that $A$ is connected, but not vice versa. One way to define a connected component is an equivalence class under the relation that $$x\sim y\text{ iff } x \text{ and } y \text{ lie in a connected subspace}.$$ The existence of equivalence classes does not require Zorn's lemma or the Axiom of Choice. *A posteriori* one can argue that components are indeed maximal connected subspaces, but since you've already proven they exist, you don't need Zorn's Lemma.

Comment: Very clever. Thanks

Comment: But I would still like some clarity on my definition. Here you define connected components differently, but I believe that is just for namesake to show maximal connected subspaces exists w.r.t my definition?

Comment: @willhart: your definition is not standard. It would imply that every connected subspace of $\mathbb R^2$ is a component, whereas in the usual definition only $\mathbb R^2$ is a component.